# Label element placement in HTML

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, label

I wanna put a label("country") below a select statement("country dropdown") and no matter what I try I just couldn't make it happen. I am new to web design. Any advice would be awesome. Thank you.

[image]

If you see the bottom right, you'll see country label next to the dropdown. I want it under it like the rest of the code.

```
<div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-4" style="padding-left:0px">
         <input class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="5">
         <label class="description">Postal/Zip code</label>
      </div>

      <div class="countryDropdown col-xs-4" style="float:right" >
      <select name="dropdown" id="myCountry">
         <option value="select">Please Select</option>
          <option value="US">United States</option>
          <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
          <option value="INDIA">India</option>
      </select>
      <label class="description" >Country</label>
      </div>
```

Comment: Could you add your code as text ?

Comment: OK, a few things are wrong here. 1) You shouldn't be posting images of text. Your code should be in the question itself as text. See [mcve]. 2) You can't nest columns like that in Bootstrap; a column has to be inside a row. 3) Bootstrap columns layout next to each other so even if they weren't nested, this wouldn't work.

Comment: ok il add code as text. sorry. even if i deleted the cols it still didnt work. i tried it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below css

```
  #myCountry{
    width: 100%;
  }
  .countryDropdown label{
    clear: both;
  }
```